# GIT: how to remove a push that is in the middle of the working tree

Tags: git

Hi for ilustration purposes this is the tree at the server.

> ```
> (...)
> Change to E from user TTT
> Change to D from user LLL
> Change to C from user me
> Change to B from user QQQ
> Change to A from user TTT
> (...)
> ```

I accidentally pushed C, how can I remove it from the main repository without affecting all the work my colleages pushed afterwards?

And if possible still keeping it as a local commit for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want is `git revert`. It creates a commit to cancel out another commit:

```
git revert <SHA1 C>
```

You can then push that to the main repository, and the change made by the commit will be reverted, while still leaving the commit itself (and subsequent history) intact:

```
- A - B - C - D - E - ... - C' - ...
```

To continue working based on it yourself, you can then revert the revert, or cherry-pick the original commit - hopefully on a local branch so you won't accidentally push it!